# Install Shield 2009 Premier : Install Windows Installer 3.1 or 2.0 (best fit for system) with any sysem restart

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installshield, restart

Basic MSI project, from release wizard I chose Install Windows Installer 3.1 or 2.0 (best fit for system), extract from setup.exe. When in installation, after installing Windows installer system restarts. Can this restart be stopped anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I am in Installshield 2008, and in the release wizard there is an option "Delay engine reboot until after your installation completes". Have you enabled this option?

Comment: Hi Glytzhkof, no I didn't enable "Delay engine reboot until after your installation completes" option when selecting the MSI engine version. But I chose "Version 1.1" which doesn't require the delay reboot option and for now i'm not facing any problem. But will there be any problem in future?